# I want to make first option in dropdown to display as a placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two phone number in my form, one is mobile phone number and another us home phone number. I have to make only one mandatory in that. Can anyone please suggest me how to aceheive thus

Comment: have you tried anything from your side? Please share some relevant code so that we can help you.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> require_from_group:

function of jQuery validation.

for example use same class for your both input fields.

> $( "#form" ).validate({
>
> rules: {
>
> ```
> mobileno: {
>
>   require_from_group: [1, ".phone1"]
> },
> homeno: {
>   require_from_group: [1, ".phone1"]
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> });
>
> <input type="text" class="phone1" id="mobileno" name="mobileNo" />
>
> <input type="text" class="phone1" id="homeno" name="homeNo" />

Hope this will help you out.